# can't get out of the loop when typing a specific command

Tags: c

I really can't see why I can't get out of this loop when typing "exit":

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char cmd[500];
    do {
        printf("$ > ");
        fgets(cmd, 499, stdin);
        //executeCommand(cmd);

    } while (strcmp(cmd, "exit") != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp(cmd, "exit")` --> `strcmp(cmd, "exit\n")`

Comment: You forgot the trailing newline... fgets returns that too.